# Stock comments for new users

Tags: discussion, closing, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard comments for flags/downvotes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/standard-comments-for-flags-downvotes)

What's a polite, clear, useful comment to throw up on posts by new users that may not understand the format or particular rules of our site?

Edit categories (answers) as you please.

Comment: Didn't someone already suggest this and it was discouraged due to being impersonal and robotic?

Answer (score 0):

### Gaming Recommendations

> Welcome to the site! Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic for [a number of reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). There is [a general question about how to discover new games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/gaming-resources-how-can-i-find-new-games-to-play) that might be useful to you instead. Please see the [FAQ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on what questions to ask here.

Source of the above, for easy copy-and-pasting:

`Welcome to the site! Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic for [a number of reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). There is [a general question about how to discover new games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/gaming-resources-how-can-i-find-new-games-to-play) that might be useful to you instead. Please see the [FAQ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on what questions to ask here.`