# Userscript for automatic stock comments

Tags: discussion, closing, comments

> *If you disagree with the spirit of [automatic comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/standard-comments-for-flags-downvotes) or [stock comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/stock-comments-for-new-users) for common issues, stop reading.*

Arda pointed out the ["Pro-forma Comments" userscript on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments) as an easy way to paste commonly used comments to avoid retyping them over and over.

Clicking a button near the comment box:

[image]

Pulls up a screen that you can use to add a stock comment:

[image]

(the "game-rec" one was added)

Comment: This post left me wanting for more. It's like I was at the first line and then it suddenly ended.

Comment: Nice, I might modify it to say the things *I* normally say.

Comment: Even if I don't like the method, I do find it good that you're helping provide this script to those who use it. Not a bad tool.

Answer (score 4):

I use this for the standard FAQ-prohibited question types when I moderate, just to ensure that the person understands why the question was closed, and where to find more information.  As "new user experience" is a topic of discussion recently, I thought sharing was in order.

**The only caution I'd give:** Let's make sure we don't spam people with stuff like this - if you use this, make sure you check back and make sure other people didn't leave identical comments.  No use beating people over the head with something of this nature.

You're welcome to use my templates.  An update to the script now allows for pulling them from a remote server, and I've checked mine into my [github repo](https://raw.github.com/agent86ix/stackapps/gh-pages/proforma/pf.js) where I keep all things SE-related.

I've modified many of the "stock" comments, as I didn't find that they were broadly applicable and often didn't make sense when leaving them.  I've also added several new ones that I leave before deleting answers, explaining the deletion and, when possible, linking to the FAQ.